# Слияние веток в Git с приоритетом одной из них

Tags: git-merge

1. Есть общий коммит (коммит_1) у двух веток: master и feature.
2. В ветке master удалил несколько файлов, добавил код в другие файлы и закоммитил изменение (коммит_2).
3. В ветке feature эти файлы не удалял, и добавил некоторый код, закоммитив его (коммит 3).

Теперь я хочу слить обе ветки таким образом, чтобы у меня остались все наработки ветки feature, и добавились наработки из master. Но при слиянии веток у меня происходит удаление тех файлов, которые я удалил при работе в ветке master. Как выполнить правильно слияние веток в этом случае?

Comment: Не понимаю. Вы же по какой-то причине удалили эти файлы из основной ветки master? Следовательно, они Вам больше не нужны. Если нужны - то не следовало их удалять. Если удалили по ошибке - отмените коммит на ветке master с сохранением изменений, восстановите удалённые файлы и заново создайте коммит.

Comment: @Dmitriy Да, были не нужны. Но вот передумал, и файлы опять понадобились.Что значит "отмените коммит на ветке мастер с сохранением изменений"? Если я сделаю Reset ветки мастер до общего коммита, то разумеется, файлы опять появятся, но потеряются наработки, которые были сделаны после удаления файлов.

Comment: Если у Reset не будет дополнительных флагов, то изменения сохранятся: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772134/can-i-delete-a-git-commit-but-keep-the-changes. А потом ищите в списке изменений удалённые файлы и отменяйте удаление.